# Как с помощью rest-assured библиотеки выполнить HTTPS запрос на сервер?

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Использую Rest_Assured библиотеку для возможности тестирования REST-запросов через https - протокол. Вопрос заключается в том, как rest-assured библиотека поможет установить https-соединение и выполнит Get/Post запрос на сервер?

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().when().post("https://мой-сервак.com")
```

Comment: Спасибо, да, нашел тоже такой способ.

Comment: @RustamMekhtiev Если вопрос помог вам решить проблему, то его следует отметить как принятый, чекбокс находится слева от ответа.

Comment: @ДенисКондратов Этот ответ был дан 5 лет назад. Я не понимаю какое отношение твой комент имеет отношение к моему ответу? Ни ты ни ОП даже не проголосовали за него.

Comment: Так я не автор, я не могу принять ответ.

Comment: Коммент оставил в надежде получить ответ на вопрос "как отправить запрос", только с сертификатами.

Comment: @ДенисКондратов Ты уже 4 года на стэковерфлоу, должен знать что комменты нельзя ставить на ответы не имеющие отношения к вопросу.